# How to add Zoom controls in Google Map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api

I want to show zoom in(+) and zoom out option (-)at right side bottom corner in my  google map. I tried this but I'm not getting the zoom option.

```
 <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDQ2&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.44633567526379, 78.38290556613924),
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
                alert("Latitude: " + e.latLng.lat() + "\r\nLongitude: " + e.latLng.lng());
                document.getElementById("txtLongitude").value = e.latLng.lng();
                document.getElementById("txtLatitude").value = e.latLng.lat();
            });
        }
    </script>
    <div id="dvMap" style="width: 700px; height: 300px">
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, including any HTML/CSS required.  [I get a +/- zoom in/out control in the bottom right corner with the posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/35rsc4je/2/).

Comment: i think my mistake was i gave more width of the map.so the zoom symbol not getting visible. when i make width smaller i got the symbols.sorry for my silly mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `zoomControl: true` in your MapOptions like this:

```
var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.44633567526379, 78.38290556613924),
                zoomControl: true,
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
```